# Form dropdown function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to work with the form dropdown function for the codeigniter form helper.

```
echo form_dropdown('userCharacters', $userRoster, '', '', 'id="userCharacter"');
```

If you notice the `$userRoster` is the array I pass from the controller to the view.

Here's how it shows up when I do a print_r on the array.

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [rosterName] => Kid Wonder
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 3
        [rosterName] => Oriel
    )

)
```

However I am getting these errors and not sure why

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: 4096

Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Filename: helpers/form_helper.php

Line Number: 352
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: 4096

Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Filename: helpers/form_helper.php

Line Number: 352
```

**EDIT :**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [rosterName] => Kid Wonder
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [rosterName] => Oriel
    )

)
```

**EDIT 2 :** 
What's supposed to happen is after the user logs in it has the default character id and the role id of the user that is held in the userData array. It runs the library function getRosterList. Inside that function it checks to see if the user has a role id of 4(admin) or 5(superadmin) and if they are then what I want it to do is get ALL the roster members which would include their default character and have it as the selected option. If they are not one of those two roles then I just want it to get the roster members that they control and have the preselected option as the default character id. And if they only have one character then it displays a h1 tag instead of the dropdown.

Controller:

```
$this->data['userData'] =   $this->users->getUserByUserID($this->session->userdata('userID'));
$this->data['userRoster'] = $this->kowauth->getRosterList($this->data['userData']->usersRolesID);
```

Library (kowauth)

```
 * Get roster list
 *
 * @param   integer
 * @return  object/NULL
 */
function getRosterList($usersRolesID)
{
    // Check args
    if(!is_numeric($usersRolesID)) { throw new Exception('Non-numeric $usersRolesID provided to getRosterList()'); }

    if (($usersRolesID == 4) || ($usersRolesID == 5))
    {
        return $this->ci->users->getAllRoster();
    } 
    else
    {
        return $this->ci->users->getRosterByUserID($this->ci->session->userdata('userID'));
    }
}
```

Model:

```
/**
 * Get roster list
 *
 * @return  object/NULL
 */
function getAllRoster()
{       
    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->select('rosterName');
    $this->db->select('rosterStatusID');
    $this->db->from('rosterList');
    $this->db->order_by('rosterName');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        return $query->result();
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Get list of roster by user ID
 *
 * @return  object/NULL
 */
function getRosterByUserID($userID)
{
    // Check args
    if (!is_numeric($userID)) { throw new Exception('Non-numeric $userID provided to getRosterByUserID()'); }

    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->select('rosterName');
    $this->db->from('rosterList');
    $this->db->where('userID', $userID);
    $this->db->order_by('rosterName');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        return $query->result_array();
    }
    return null;
}
```

View:

```
<?php 
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($userRoster);
        echo '</pre>';
        if (count($userRoster) == 1)
        {
            echo '<h1>'.$userRoster->rosterName.'</h1>';
        }
        else 
        {
            $options = array (
                $userRoster['id'] => $userRoster->rosterName
            );
            echo form_dropdown('userCharacters', $options, '', 'id="userCharacter"');
        }
        ?>
```

Anybody have any ideas on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're currently passing an array of objects.  I believe that your $userRoster array should be formatted like this:

```
Array
(
     1 => 'Kid Wonder'
     3 => 'Oriel'
)
```

Also, I believe that form_dropdown only takes four parameters and you're trying to pass it five.  You might want to move that last argument into the fourth spot:

```
echo form_dropdown('userCharacters', $userRoster, '', 'id="userCharacter"');
```

Should produce:

```
<select name="userCharacters" id="userCharacter">
<option value="1">Kid Wonder</option>
<option value="3">Oriel</option>
</select>
```

Which I *think* is what you're going for!

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Comment: @user1296102 Passing a multidimensional array will create optgroups, but not the way you're doing it in your updated question (with the associative array having keys of 'id' and 'rosterName' - CI won't look for those keys so it won't know what to do and even if it did you'd have the optgroup labels of '0' and '1' since you're using integers as keys for the top-level array).  I think you just want to pass an array with one dimension like I have above, but do let me know if you want those optgroups and I'll update my answer!

Comment: Do you use CI in your projects?

Comment: I do when I can, but I don't often use the form helper to construct select elements.  However, I'm pretty sure the array structure that I posted above will work for you! :)

Comment: Well this part of my script is just getting confusing for me and can't get it to work because of other conditions. I tried on codereview and got a response but its still not working. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/10574/updating-old-code-into-code-igniter-use

Comment: I made a big update on my post to describe what I'm trying to do.